# How to create dynamic database connection in adf application?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

any body please tell me.how to create dynamic connection in adf fusion web application?

where I get information about it.

Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by a dynamic connection in adf? Are you referring to a connection that is shared across multiple applications? And if you are, see this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257435/sharing-database-connection-between-applications

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you need to use dynamic credentionals, then you should implement your own class (HttpSessionCookieFactory) for property jbo.ampool.sessioncockiefactoryclass in bc4j.xcfg.
For more detailed info look at:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/dynamicjdbchowto-101755.html